# Powershell find file in one location over write in another based on name

Tags: arrays, file, powershell, find, move

I'm a beginner when it comes to powershell but recently I've been asked to create a script for the infrastructure guys.

Basically I have a list of file names in a text file.
The files exist in two different locations, lets say locationA and locationB. The files could be sitting in different sub-folders within the folder root.

What I need to do is find each file listed in the text file.
Search for the file in locationA then find the file in locationB, more than likely a different folder structure then over write the file in the same location where it exists in locationB with the file in locationA.

I'm assuming this will need to be done through an array. What I'm having trouble with is finding the files in each location and then over write the associated by file name.

Any help will be greatly appreciated. I've just come across this site and intend to use it a lot more in future.

My code so far:

```
$FileList = 'C:\File_Names.txt' 
$Src ='\\server\Temp' 
$Dst ='\\server\Testing' 

Foreach ($File in $FileList) { 
    Get-ChildItem $Src -Name -Recurse $File
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$FileList = 'C:\File_Names.txt' 
$Src ='\\server\Temp' 
$Dst ='\\server\Testing' 

Get-ChildItem $Src -Recurse -Include (Get-Content $FileList) | ForEachObject {
  $destFile = Get-ChildItem $Dst -Recurse -Filter $_.Name
  switch ($destFile.Count) {
    0 { Write-Warning "No matching target file found for: $_"; break }
    1 { Copy-Item $_.FullName $destFile.FullName }
    default { Write-Warning "Multiple target files found for: $_" }
  }
}
```

- `Get-ChildItem $Src -Recurse -Include (Get-Content $FileList)` searches the subtree of `$Src` for any files whose name is contained in file `$FileList` (`-Include` operates on the leaf (file-name) components of the paths only, and accepts an *array* of names, which is what `Get-Content` returns by default).
- `Get-ChildItem $Dst -Recurse -Filter $_.Name` searches the subtree of `$Dst` for a file of the same name (`$_.Name`); note that `-Filter` is used in this case, which is preferable for performance reasons, but only an option with a *single* name / name pattern.
- The `switch` statement then ensures that copy action is only taken if exactly *1* file in the destination subtree matches.
- In the `Copy-Item` call, accessing the source and destination file's `.FullName` property ensures that the files are referenced unambiguously.

Comment: Definitely more efficient than my script. +1

Comment: @MavCoder: Sorry to hear it; nothing readily comes to mind. I suggest you ask a _new_ question that describes the problem in more detail, ideally by way of an [MCVE (Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

```
$FileList = Get-Content 'C:\File_Names.txt' 
$SrcDir ='\\server\Temp' 
$DstDir ='\\server\Testing' 
Foreach ($File in $FileList) { 
    $SrcFile = Get-ChildItem $SrcDir -Recurse $File -EA SilentlyContinue
    $DstFile = Get-ChildItem $DstDir -Recurse $File -EA SilentlyContinue
    if (($Srcfile.count -eq 1) -and ($DstFile.count -eq 1)){
        Copy-Item $SrcFile $DstFile
    } Else {
        "More/less than one Source and/or Destination file $File"
    }
}
```